# Create table sql in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my query in sql. It seems to say I have a syntax error. I'm used to coding in SQL Server not Access fo I expected this outcome. If anyone could help me correct my code I'd really appreciate it!

```
 create table  M (
 NMR_METER_PT_REF Varchar (50) ,
 NMR_ST_METER_READ_DATE Datetime,
 NMR_END_METER_READ_DATE datetime,
 NMR_ST_METER_READING Int,
 NMR_END_METER_READING int,
 RCH_RECONCILIATION_QTY int,
 METERS_THROUGH_ZEROS_COUNT int);

INSERT M (

SELECT 
NMR_METER_PT_REF
, NMR_ST_METER_READ_DATE
, NMR_END_METER_READ_DATE
, NMR_ST_METER_READING
, NMR_END_METER_READING
, RCH_RECONCILIATION_QTY
, METERS_THROUGH_ZEROS_COUNT
 FROM G
 WHERE  (((NMR.ST.METER_READING) <= NMR.ST.METER_READING)))


select * from M
drop table M
;
```

Comment: can you explain how you expect to select from M after dropping M?

Comment: i appologise i ment it the other way around typo

Comment: im getting an error in the INSERT access is highlighting the insert

Comment: use the `INSERT INTO [tablename] SELECT * FROM [table2]` syntax

Comment: Also, TSQL lets you declare temp tables. This would be better than creating a table specifically for this query, then dropping it afterwards.

Comment: this is an access database can it still be done

Comment: access uses SQL, and its something all versions of SQL can do - declaring temp tables and variables.

Comment: no g is the database as restrictions from the company i work for i cant put full names of DB's

Comment: no G is the database 

select * from G ..... ? (  it has a real name ive just aliased it )

Comment: nope because of the systems used the 7 clock reading would get to 9999999 then what ? go back to 0 ,
im essentially looking for 
anything that jumped because of human error 
say someones meter was on 9830219 < ---- then someone else comes along and enters 990211 6 characters   that would  mean the clock had been all the way round and back up to that number

Answer (score 0):

First of all droping table after insert is insane :)

Second specify column list when using `INSERT`:

```
create table  M (
 NMR_METER_PT_REF Varchar (50) ,
 NMR_ST_METER_READ_DATE Datetime,
 NMR_END_METER_READ_DATE datetime,
 NMR_ST_METER_READING Int,
 NMR_END_METER_READING int,
 RCH_RECONCILIATION_QTY int,
 METERS_THROUGH_ZEROS_COUNT int);

INSERT M (  NMR_METER_PT_REF
  , NMR_ST_METER_READ_DATE
  , NMR_END_METER_READ_DATE
  , NMR_ST_METER_READING
  , NMR_END_METER_READING
  , RCH_RECONCILIATION_QTY
  , METERS_THROUGH_ZEROS_COUNT)
SELECT 
   NMR_METER_PT_REF
  , NMR_ST_METER_READ_DATE
  , NMR_END_METER_READ_DATE
  , NMR_ST_METER_READING
  , NMR_END_METER_READING
  , RCH_RECONCILIATION_QTY
  , METERS_THROUGH_ZEROS_COUNT
 FROM G
 WHERE NMR.ST.METER_READING <= NMR.ST.METER_READING;  -- always true

 -- drop table M
 select * from M;
 drop table M;
```

Finally your `WHERE` condition refer to object that is not specified in `FROM` clause.

**EDIT:**

If you want temporary table in SQL Server you could use [temporary table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

```
SELECT 
   NMR_METER_PT_REF
  , NMR_ST_METER_READ_DATE
  , NMR_END_METER_READ_DATE
  , NMR_ST_METER_READING
  , NMR_END_METER_READING
  , RCH_RECONCILIATION_QTY
  , METERS_THROUGH_ZEROS_COUNT
INTO #M
FROM G
-- WHERE  NMR.ST.METER_READING <= NMR.ST.METER_READING --??

SELECT * FROM #M;
```

Comment: that makes no sence , im creating a temporary table within access , how can i insert data into M when you took out the creation of M

Comment: as you can see im inserting the select into the insert

Answer (score 0):

So in summary:

- You can't put all these statements into one query. Every part (CREATE / INSERT / SELECT / DROP) must be executed in a **separate** query.
- `INSERT` must be `INSERT INTO`
- the WHERE clause `WHERE  (((NMR.ST.METER_READING) <= NMR.ST.METER_READING))` compares a field with itself.

Comment: i know this, this is the intention